# Grail: Error handling in @BindUsing

Tags: grails, data-binding, grails3

I have tried to use @BindUsing for a property (amt100) of a domain class (TcTransaction). The purpose is to convert a display format to a database format. Out of a dozen variants, here is one:

```
@BindUsing({tcTransaction, source ->
  def result = tcTransaction.amt100
  def amt = Amount100.of(source['amt100']) //parse and convert input
  if (amt) {
    result = amt.cents
  } else {
    tcTransaction.errors.rejectValue('amt100', 'tcTransaction.invalid.amount')
  }
  return result
      })
Integer amt100
```

It works beautifully in the absence of errors. The problem is error management. This particular version returns the original value if the new value is invalid. It also adds an error to the domain object.

It seems adding to errors has no effect. The user is not warned.

I also tried to throw an exception. It seems whatever exception you throw you end up with a standard error code saying that the property must not be left empty. A [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253601/how-to-handle-errors-that-occur-in-bindusing-annotation-closure) indicated this behaviour. (It has gone unanswered for two years.) I'm on Grails 3.2.8.

So, is there any theory of error management in @BindUsing? It's such a nifty mechanism.

Comment: Hi sodastream! Were you able to solve the issue? I'm facing the same problem. Whatever exception I throw in @BindUsing it gets mangled into something else. There is no documentation on how to properly handle exceptions.

Comment: I got around with a hack... . My question mentions amount. Another example is a Swedish zip code. Both are integers with a particular display format, each has a dedicated class. I created a "nullOnError" method for them that scans an input string and returns null if invalid. The method is used in @BindUsing and also in the controller where I repeat the check on the original input field, typically in an "update" action. I never managed to have exceptions work for me.